# Why is the first sprite from the next row invisible?

Tags: java, sprite

## What I'm trying to do

Convert my sprite sheet into separate buffered images, of which, each will be stored in a an array.
 The way I'm doing is from the top, down and from left to right.

## The issue:

When I go through all the elements and get to the 1st element of the next row.
 The image is blank, however, all elements following show as intended.

## Illustration:

#### Note: The location is the same for each element.

Sprite sheet:
Link: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/153/ljsh.png/
As it appears:
Link: "http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/t3be.png/"
Anyone can use the sprite sheet if they want to.
Need more reputation for the images. :/

## Code:

#### Note: I'm still very new to Java, so please, be gentle ;)

I think the problem is within the `for` loop that's in the `loadSpriteSheet` method.
Although what the cause is exactly, I have no idea.

How it works, from my understanding is that:

- Loads sprite sheet image.
- Array of buffered images is created based on the amount of rows and columns input by user.

The size is calculated `SizeX = image.width / columns`, `SizeY = image.height / rows`.

- Graphics object draws to the current element in the array.
- The sprite sheet is moved -SizeX.
- The next element is drawn.
- Repeats until x = columns.
- Starts next row, sprite sheet is moved -SizeY.
- Continues the same as before.

The "System.out" part shows the location of tX and tY exactly where I would expect them to be.

```
public class SpriteSheet extends ImageObject {
// Variables
protected BufferedImage[] spriteSheet;
protected AffineTransform sprSheetAt;

// Getters
public int getLength()                          {return spriteSheet.length;}

// Setters

// Constructor
public SpriteSheet(JFrame a) {
    super(a);
}

public void loadSpriteSheet(String filename, int rows, int columns) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sprSheetAt = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);

    // Size of sprite image.
    int spriteSX = image.getWidth() / columns;
    int spriteSY = image.getHeight() / rows;

    int tX = 0;
    int tY = 0;

    spriteSheet = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];

    int spriteInd = 0;

    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {                  
            Graphics2D g;

            if(spriteInd >= spriteSheet.length) {
                break;
            }

            spriteSheet[spriteInd] = new BufferedImage(spriteSX, spriteSY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            g = spriteSheet[spriteInd].createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, sprSheetAt, null);                   
            g.dispose();

            System.out.println(spriteInd + ", tX: " + tX + ", tY: " + tY);

            tX -= spriteSX;

            spriteInd++;

            sprSheetAt.setToTranslation(tX, tY);    
        }
        tX = 0;
        tY -= spriteSY;     
    }
}

public void drawSprite(Graphics2D g, int spriteInd) {
    g2d = g;

    if(alive) {
        g2d.drawImage(spriteSheet[spriteInd], 0, 0, frame);             
    }       
}
}
```

I hope I explained this clearly, my apologies if I have not.

Thank you in advanced for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure why your subtracting the tx and ty, when they start at 0x0. You can also use [BufferedImage#subImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to return a new BufferedImage from the. Ian BufferedImage

Comment: Thank you. As for the reason I was subtracting, imagine a piece of card with a square cut out to the size of the sprite, you put the original image under the card, you line it up so that the hole and the first sprite line up. In order to move over to the next sprite along the x-axis (In this case anyway) you have to move the original `-x`, same with the `y` for the next row.

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking again, at other sprite/sprite sheet related questions, I came across `BufferedImage.getSubimage`. (I noticed just before I posted this that it was suggested)

And thus I immediately implemented it.
I changed the inner most `for` loop that's within the `loadSpriteSheet` method to.

```
    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {                                                      
            spriteSheet[spriteInd] = new BufferedImage(spriteSX, spriteSY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            System.out.println(spriteInd + ", tX: " + tX + ", tY: " + tY);

            spriteSheet[spriteInd] = image.getSubimage(tX, tY, spriteSX, spriteSX); 

            tX += spriteSX;

            spriteInd++;
        }
        tX = 0;
        tY += spriteSY;     
    }
```

It's much shorter and actually works now  :D

So from this I have learned a few things.
1. Do more googling and general searching.
2. Check the api more.
3. And wait until I've spent a long time searching to ask :)

Despite this, I would like to know what the cause of the issue was.

Comment: The issue was the order of setting the transformation. You set `tX = 0` but didn't set the translation before the next draw. I was about to post an answer, but good that you found the better way before.